# Number of cores used by local[*]

Tags: apache-spark

In this [talk on YouTube](https://youtu.be/7ooZ4S7Ay6Y?t=5569), the speaker states that we should specificy a higher number than the number of logical cores when using master as `local[N]`.

He states than `local[*]` isn't optimal then.

However this video is a bit old. Is it still relevant to do so ?

Comment: Even if standalone spark is mainly for testing purposes **please just don't do that !** It's always recommended to leave one for your local system since spark is sharing resources with some other applications...

Comment: Can you elaborate please ? Also this isn't standalone but local mode I think in this case.
He answered to your point in the video, saying that people often leave 6 cores to spark out of 8 and leave two for their OS. He stated that you should double this 6 and try 12 or 18

Comment: local mode/standalone, there is no big difference here. Local mode isn't the best fit setup for spark as you can achieve much better performance with built-in undistributed libraries.

Comment: Your question is quite broad to answer here unfortunately.

Comment: You can't over allocate spark cores configuration actually.

Comment: I agree with you it seems to be weird. However this man is from databricks and was part of the team who mostly contributed to spark in the early days and he stated that their clients got much better performance after this change of setting

Comment: You have an interesting opinion, I'd give it a look.. This has indeed intrigued me

Comment: You should specify a higher number than the number of logical cores because `--num-executor-cores` is actually used to loosely specify the number of concurrent tasks an executor can run and the tasks run in threads. So you can oversubscribe, but not too much. BTW, is that Sameer Faroqui? I can't see that video :D

Comment: Ok I understand better now thanks. So it is still useful to do so in the more recent spark versions.
Haha it is Sameer indeed, learnt a lot thanks to him.

Comment: Ok, here it is, I've just ran an experience with some application that I have written, *oversubscribing* is a real thing in Spark, nevertheless, it seems to hit some kind of threshold if too much. I have doubled at first the number of cores available, it seems like there is performance gain (in local mode).

Comment: But when I doubled again (8 -> 16 -> 32), the application crashes with the following error : `java.io.FileNotFoundException [...] (Too many open files)`

Comment: @eliasah Most probably because the usual CPU core has 2 threads, maybe?

Comment: The solution to that problem would be describe [here](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/quot-Too-many-open-files-quot-exception-on-reduceByKey-td2462.html) which mainly is to increase the `ulimit` if possible

Comment: Indeed @philantrovert !

Comment: It's a very interesting hack nevertheless, but I would use that for other than local. @TiffanyHatsune +1 !